# R for each row calculate a sum taking values of one of the columns from the rows BEFORE that satisfy special condition

Tags: r, performance, loops, apply

I am using R. I have a big dataset of more than 400K lines. Here is the code to reproduce 5 lines of similar data frame:

```
Date = as.Date(c("2013-01-03", "2013-01-03", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-05"))
CustomerID = as.factor(c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A"))
PurchaseNS = c(13, 14, 12, 8, 10)
df = data.frame(Date, CustomerID, PurchaseNS)

> df
        Date CustomerID PurchaseNS
1 2013-01-03          A         13
2 2013-01-03          B         14
3 2013-01-04          A         12
4 2013-01-04          C          8
5 2013-01-05          A         10
```

What I need is to add an additional column that for an each row equals to the sum of previous purchases of this customer. So in the end I am trying to get next data frame:

```
> df
        Date CustomerID PurchaseNS previousPurchases
1 2013-01-03          A         13                 0
2 2013-01-03          B         14                 0
3 2013-01-04          A         12                13
4 2013-01-04          C          8                 0
5 2013-01-05          A         10                25
```

I can achieve that with for loop, but it takes too much time and I know that it's not recommended to use loops in R.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[i, 4] = sum(subset(df, df$CustomerID == df$CustomerID[i] & df$Date < df$Date[i])$PurchaseNS)
}
```

I also tried using `sapply`, but the code ends up looking similar to the one above and also takes too much time.

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df[i, 4] = 
     sum(subset(df, df$CustomerID == df$CustomerID[i] & df$Date < df$Date[i])$Purchase))
```

I guess, functions like `by`, `with`, `cumsum`, `apply` could be useful, but so far I was not able to apply them.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df$prevPurch <- ave(
  df$PurchaseNS, df$CustomerID, 
  FUN=function(x) cumsum(c(0, head(x, -1)))
)
```

which produces:

```
#         Date CustomerID PurchaseNS prevPurch
# 1 2013-01-03          A         13         0
# 2 2013-01-03          B         14         0
# 3 2013-01-04          A         12        13
# 4 2013-01-04          C          8         0
# 5 2013-01-05          A         10        25
```

`ave` breaks up a vector by the groups in another vector, and then applies a function to each group.

Comment: I was working on a somewhat similar `tapply` solution, but this is much nicer!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly! I was not aware of `ave` function before.